# Delete item from listview and database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to delete an item from a listview and from a sqlite database. There are several question on this site but I can't find a proper solution. My question is related with the *design*. I mean: the database access on Android should be done in async way to avoid to stop the main thread. My current listview, indeed, is loaded using an android *Loader* that it notified about any operation on the db and call `onContentChanged()`. The problem is how to proceed with the deletion: what is the best strategy? I see two ways:

1. Delete from adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it and then delete from db with an `AsyncTask` (or similar). The Loader will be notified. In this case there is maybe a refresh problem because the adapter is updated again due to loader update.
2. Delete the item using an AsyncTask (or similar) and wait the update using the *Loader*. In this case the problem is that the UI is not updated when the user delete the item, but it's going to be deleted later (if no error occur) so it can be a bit weird from user point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both option will work, but different people will pick different way. The second way easier and more recommended as far as you leave all of the work to `Loader`, developed by `Google`. 
The [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#onLoadFinished) said it will refresh the data automatically and need to work just with callbacks as `onLoadFinished` and `onLoadReset` to complete it:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

And "clean" adapter when `Loader` was reset:

```
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Another words, I don't see any reason to pick first method, when second is making life easier.

Comment: I know, but in this case, as I said the item is not deleted when the user push the delete button but later in the time, so it can be a bit strange.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "is not deleted"?  Delay deleting? This is the way to how handle user input and about the logic of the program, `Loader` will reload, only when something changed in database, not before. While deleting show the dialog to wait (if data to remove is really big).

Comment: Ok, so you are saying, to "cover" the posible delay, use a dialog or something similar. It can work, thanks :)

Comment: The dialog in case to not let user press all buttons chaotically at the same time. If needs exactly "delayed" so may use or `TimerTask` or `Handler` or something else. Cheers :)